# Implement dynamic values

Tags: swagger

I am trying to implement this request:

```
curl -ik -X POST "https://<HOST_IP>/api/v1/roles/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "x-access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6IjVlMGM0Nzg0OGZiMDNhMzJmMTc0Nzc0NSIsInNvdXJjZSI6bnVsbCwicGVybWlzc2lvbnMiOnsiQUxMIjpbdHJ1ZV19LCJpYXQiOjE1Nzc4NzY0ODIsImV4cCI6MTU3NzkxOTY4Mn0.Z-WJ7ouQ5XdDqNvxMgTc-74qgW4sShtJrqTaEH-rykA" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"users\":[{\"id\":\"5e0c47848fb03a32f1747745\",\"title\":\"admin\"}],\"groups\":null,\"permissions\":{\"ISSUES\":[\"All\"]},\"devicePermissions\":null,\"name\":\"role name\",\"description\":\"\"}"
```

I have this request body:

```
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "5e0c47848fb03a32f1747745",
      "title": "admin"
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": "5e0c8f0d8a2c1676ed67fd2e",
      "title": "asgsagas"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": {
    "ISSUES": [
      "All"
    ],
    "RULES": [
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "devicePermissions": null,
  "name": "gasgag",
  "description": ""
}
```

where under "permissions" object I can add (optional) additional string arrays , But I am struggling how to implement it, should I implement all options? how can I make it generic?

This is how I implemented it:

```
permissions:
        type: object
        properties:
          ISSUES:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          KNOWLEDGE_EXPLORER:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "Archive"
          ANALYSIS_AND_REPORTS:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          DEVICES:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          CREDENTIALS_MANAGEMENT:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          BACKUPS:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          ABOUT:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          INTEGRATIONS:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          USERS:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          AUDIT:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          APPLICATION_SETTINGS:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          DEV_TOOLS:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
          OTHER:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              example: "All"
```

I am using java in order to use this api request and I can see that maybe my implementation is not correct.

This is the expected response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "code": "",
  "message": "Create was success",
  "hasException": false,
  "exception": null,
  "errors": [],
  "info": null,
  "content": {
    "devicePermissions": {
      "showAll": true,
      "labels": []
    },
    "_id": "5e0cb0ed8a2c1676ed67fd56",
    "name": "devices_delete_labels_role_278932055218587",
    "description": "New Role added to the system",
    "permissions": {},
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-01T14:47:09.792Z",
    "createdAt": "2020-01-01T14:47:09.792Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Your definition of the `permissions` object looks correct. What problem do you have with it? What do you mean by "make it generic"?

Comment: I mean that I don't have to add any item of the permissions and I wanted to understand if I can skip declaring those options, also how may I send the request ? (I am using java that generates the swagger implementation).